# Unable to connect to Internet on a VM (NAT & Host only networks enabled)

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualization

- Host machine: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Guest machine: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Networking mode: NAT + Host Network only.

Settings of my VM:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces:
```

Output:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
      address 10.0.0.4
      netmask 255.255.255.0 

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

When I run : `ping 8.8.8.8`, I get: *connect: network is unreachable*.

Note: I run the necessary things such as: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` and `sudo service network-interface restart INTERFACE=eth0/eth1`, and even `sudo ifconfig eth0/eth1 down/up`.
I also edited the necessary files: `/etc/hosts` where I added my ip (10.0.0.4) and I added my dns namserver (that i also definied for eth0 - I just do not want to post it here) to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

When I run `route -n`, I get this output:
[image]

`ifconfig` gives me this: 
[image]

How could I connect to internet using a static address of my choice ?

Comment: Are you sure that the eth0 is host only & the eth1 is exaclty facing the NAT? Further, I would like to see the outputs for `ifconfig`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` & `route -n`. Also, I would like to know why there is NAT & host only adapter in place?

Comment: @AzkerM `Are you sure that the eth0 is host only & the eth1 is exaclty facing the NAT? `: How could I know that ?

Comment: @AzkerM I need `NAT` in order to access to Inernet from my VM. In `/etc/resolv.conf` I have written my dns nameserver's address and it is still there. For the `route -n`, I edited my question.

Comment: Which one stays first on the networking tab from VM settings to the guest? Assuming, if the first tab is selected to NAT, then you should probably update the static IP's to eth1 rather than to eth0.  Because, I don't see any IP's assigned onto eth1 and no routes to connect to the internet whilst no NAT'ing available yet from the host. Whatever the DNS you update to `resolv.conf` are not permenant and will be flushed on your next restart. Post a screen of the VM network settings.

Comment: @AzkerM thank you very much for what you said about the interfaces, i never heard about that before. For `resolv.conf` it is not flushed after restart because i edited `base` file which generates the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`. But one remark, if i may: eth1 and eth0 are just names, you can call them as you want so I do not understand why it is important to change the static/dhcp feature of eth1/eth0

Comment: You're welcome & post us back with the results. Would like to see whether that trick worked or not.

Comment: in `/etc/network/interfaces` I set first eth0 to dhcp then eth1 to static according to your note. After running the commands above, I run ifconfig and I can not see eth0 (the dhcp one). I can see it only if i run sudo ifconfig eth0 down/up, but then no IP address is assigned to it.

Comment: I'm still curious why you need two adapters so to speak? A simple NAT or a Bridge mode will allow you internet access while host only will only be able to communicate between guest & host. I've never used host only & NAT together but I'm using NAT & Bridge when required.

Comment: @AzkerM I use bridge mode my host machine needs an additional physical internet interface according to what I read from Virtualbox documentation. I need internet so I need NAT. I use host only network because i need to communicate between the host and the VM. In the past, I i run successfully NAT and Host Only modes together, i do not remember the settings i did

Comment: @AzkerM I am using NAT mode only. I set eth0 to dynamic and I removed eth1. I restarted everything through the command line. ifconfig gives me only the lo interface. No access to internet, no ip address is given to eth0

Comment: @AzkerM you were right on all what you said through your comment, especially what is related to interfaces. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem this way:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 10.0.0.4
      netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and I run `sudo ifconfig eth1 up`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the "*Briged network*" mode in Virtual Box settings before starting the VM. Then you would be able to access internet as usual from the Guest machine.

Comment: The briged mode needs an additional interface on the host machine, which I have not. It can work with the host network only, just something i missed must be done

Comment: Bridge mode does not need an additional interface, it will use your same LAN interface of the host & connects to the physical router or whatever as you've configured, then requests IP's from it (if DHCP available).